Issue in adding ListView and RecyclerView in Proteus Layout Engine provided by Flipkart
This is the piece of code that I'm trying to run using proteus layout engine library
private const val LAYOUT = """
    {
      "type": "RelativeLayout",
      "id": "background2",
      "layout_width": "match_parent",
      "layout_height": "match_parent",
      "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
      "layout_alignParentTop": "true",
      "layout_marginLeft": "8dp",
      "layout_marginTop": "14dp",
      "layout_marginRight": "8dp",
      "layout_marginBottom": "14dp",
      "background": "@drawable/background2",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "ImageView",
          "id": "fiu_logo",
          "layout_width": "60dp",
          "layout_height": "60dp",
          "layout_marginLeft": "23dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "28dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "23dp",
          "src": "@drawable/fiu_logo"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "we_need_to_verify",
          "layout_width": "wrap_content",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "true",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "false",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "23dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "116dp",
          "gravity": "top",
          "text": "@string/we_need_to",
          "textAppearance": "@style/we_need_to_"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "otp_sent_to",
          "layout_width": "wrap_content",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_below": "we_need_to_verify",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "false",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "false",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "23dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "10dp",
          "gravity": "top",
          "text": "@string/otp_sent_to",
          "textAppearance": "@style/otp_sent_to_"
        },
        {
          "type": "EditText",
          "id": "otp_text_field",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "32dp",
          "layout_below": "otp_sent_to",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_marginLeft": "23dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "25dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "23dp",
          "background": "@drawable/rectangle_6",
          "gravity": "center|center_horizontal|center_vertical",
          "hint": "Enter OTP",
          "inputType": "number",
          "maxLength": "6"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "resendOtp",
          "layout_width": "wrap_content",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_below": "otp_text_field",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "enabled": "false",
          "gravity": "center|top",
          "text": "@string/resend_otp",
          "textAppearance": "@style/resend_otp_",
          "visibility": "gone"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "red_toast",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_below": "resendOtp",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "20dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "40dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "20dp",
          "background": "@drawable/red_toast",
          "gravity": "center",
          "text": "@string/unable_to",
          "textAppearance": "@style/error",
          "visibility": "gone"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "green_toast",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_below": "resendOtp",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "20dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "40dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "20dp",
          "background": "@drawable/green_toast",
          "gravity": "center",
          "text": "@string/otp_verified",
          "textAppearance": "@style/error",
          "visibility": "gone"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "rbi_license",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "data_driven",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "20dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "20dp",
          "layout_marginBottom": "10dp",
          "background": "@drawable/rectangle_4",
          "gravity": "center",
          "text": "@string/rbi_licensed",
          "textAppearance": "@style/rbi_license_"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "data_driven",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "end_to_end",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "20dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "20dp",
          "layout_marginBottom": "10dp",
          "background": "@drawable/rectangle_4",
          "gravity": "center",
          "text": "@string/data_driven",
          "textAppearance": "@style/rbi_license_"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "end_to_end",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "tandcs",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "20dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "20dp",
          "layout_marginBottom": "20dp",
          "background": "@drawable/rectangle_4",
          "gravity": "center",
          "text": "@string/end_to_end",
          "textAppearance": "@style/rbi_license_"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextView",
          "id": "tandcs",
          "layout_width": "wrap_content",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "poweredby_layout",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "true",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginBottom": "95dp",
          "enabled": "false",
          "gravity": "center|top",
          "text": "@string/tandcs",
          "textAppearance": "@style/resend_otp_"
        },
        {
          "type": "ListView",
          "id": "fip_list_view",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "320dp",
          "layout_below": "tandcs",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "21dp",
          "layout_marginTop": "24dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "21dp",
          "divider": "@android:color/transparent",
          "dividerHeight": "0dp"
        },
        {
          "type": "Button",
          "id": "verify_otp",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "poweredby_layout",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "false",
          "layout_marginLeft": "25dp",
          "layout_marginRight": "25dp",
          "layout_marginBottom": "40dp",
          "background": "@drawable/primary_button",
          "enabled": "true",
          "text": "@string/verify_otp",
          "textAllCaps": "true",
          "textColor": "@color/white",
          "textSize": "20sp",
          "textStyle": "bold",
          "onClickAction": "VerifyOtp"
        },
        {
          "type": "ProgressBar",
          "id": "loader",
          "layout_width": "wrap_content",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_above": "poweredby_layout",
          "layout_centerHorizontal": "true",
          "layout_marginBottom": "40dp",
          "visibility": "gone"
        },
        {
          "type": "LinearLayout",
          "id": "poweredby_layout",
          "layout_width": "match_parent",
          "layout_height": "wrap_content",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "true",
          "layout_marginBottom": "20dp",
          "gravity": "center_horizontal",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "TextView",
              "id": "powered_by",
              "layout_width": "wrap_content",
              "layout_height": "wrap_content",
              "layout_alignParentLeft": "false",
              "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
              "layout_alignParentRight": "false",
              "layout_alignParentBottom": "true",
              "gravity": "right|center_horizontal|top",
              "text": "@string/powered_by",
              "textAppearance": "@style/powered_by"
            },
            {
              "type": "ImageView",
              "id": "logo_1",
              "layout_width": "80dp",
              "layout_height": "match_parent",
              "layout_alignParentLeft": "false",
              "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
              "layout_alignParentRight": "false",
              "layout_alignParentBottom": "true",
              "layout_marginLeft": "5dp",
              "layout_toRightOf": "powered_by",
              "src": "@drawable/primary_logo"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "ImageView",
          "id": "onemoney_logo",
          "layout_width": "176.39dp",
          "layout_height": "180dp",
          "layout_alignParentLeft": "false",
          "layout_alignParentTop": "false",
          "layout_alignParentRight": "true",
          "layout_alignParentBottom": "true",
          "src": "@drawable/onemoney_logo"
        }
      ]
    }
    """

// create a new instance of proteus
val proteus = ProteusBuilder().build()

// register proteus with a ProteusTypeAdapterFactory to deserialize proteus jsons
val adapter = ProteusTypeAdapterFactory(this)
ProteusTypeAdapterFactory.PROTEUS_INSTANCE_HOLDER.proteus = proteus

// deserialize layout and data
val layout: Layout
val data: ObjectValue
try {
    layout = adapter.LAYOUT_TYPE_ADAPTER.read(
        JsonReader(
            StringReader(
                LAYOUT
            )
        )
    )
    data = adapter.OBJECT_TYPE_ADAPTER.read(
        JsonReader(
            StringReader(
                DATA
            )
        )
    )
} catch (e: IOException) {
    throw RuntimeException(e)
}

// create a new ProteusLayoutInflater
val context = proteus.createContextBuilder(this).build()
val inflater = context.inflater


// remove the current view
container.removeAllViews()

// Inflate the layout
view = inflater.inflate(layout, data, container, 0)

Whenever I try to add ListView or RecyclerView into JSON data and run the above code the following exception is thrown.
Caused by: com.flipkart.android.proteus.exceptions.ProteusInflateException: attribute 'children' must be an array of 'Layout' objects at com.flipkart.android.proteus.parser.custom.ViewGroupParser.handleChildren(ViewGroupParser.java:163) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.parser.custom.ViewGroupParser$5.handleValue(ViewGroupParser.java:128) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.parser.custom.ViewGroupParser$5.handleValue(ViewGroupParser.java:120) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.processor.AttributeProcessor.process(AttributeProcessor.java:126) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.ViewTypeParser.handleAttribute(ViewTypeParser.java:175) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.ViewTypeParser.handleAttribute(ViewTypeParser.java:171) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.SimpleLayoutInflater.handleAttribute(SimpleLayoutInflater.java:189) at com.flipkart.android.proteus.SimpleLayoutInflater.inflate(SimpleLayoutInflater.java:103) at com.onemoney.commonuisdk.ProteusUIActivity.onCreate(ProteusUIActivity.kt:71)
Please help me to find any solution for this
